# Another, different open() returns 0

Tags: gcc

In searching the site, I found two other similar (at first glance) questions by users 2253605 
and 2135159. I also have tried two different versions of gcc.  This started out as a hard to
track problem in an application to keep various forms of data in sync on different media.  I
eventually boiled it down to a few lines of code that illustrate the problem.

This one is very defined and puzzling.  I have not been able to find a case where my system opens
a file, and returns a non-zero file descriptor.  It sometimes does really open the specified file 
and allows a subsequent read() to occur without error.  But by the third open() the 
subsequent read() fails, specifying an invalid argument, which can only be a zero value file
descriptor.

The code below tries to open 5 different files, 4 files exist and one that does not exist.

The first 4 opens all return a file descriptor value of zero (stdin).

stdin is not closed, a read() before the first open() or after any one of these open() calls, 
will hang until enter is pressed.

Even if stdin were closed, zero should only be returned for the first open().  The 
file descriptors are being set and when the open() for the non-existent file is attempted,
it returns an error.

I can't believe that gcc can't open a file.  I think I have some kind of O/S-compiler configuration 
issue (lib) or maybe I can't see the forest for the trees.

This is on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit and 64 bit gcc-4.6 also on gcc-4.7 .  The flash drive is 
formatted ext4.  x86_64 intel processor.  The installation commands used for gccc-4.7 on 2/10/16 
are also shown below.  Both gcc-4.6 and gcc-4.7 give identical results.  The makefile 
is at the end.

Anybody know what's happening here?

The terminal output is shown below the code.

```
    #include    <stdio.h>
    #include    <fcntl.h>
    #include    <unistd.h       
    #include    <errno.h>

    int main()

    {
        long ret_val;

        char cpy_buf[4096];

        char s_ary[20][80] =

        {
            "/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm1",    //0     exists
            "/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm2",    //1     exists
            "/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm3",    //2     exists
            "/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm4",    //3     exists
            "/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm5",    //4 does not exist
         };

        char *s1;
        long s_fh_1, s_fh_2, s_fh_3, s_fh_4, s_fh_5;

        s_fh_1 = 10000;

        s1 = &s_ary[0][0];

        if  (s_fh_1 = open( s1 , O_RDONLY) < 0)         // &s_ary[0][0]
            {
                printf("Error opening source file, name=%s, line# = %i,   errno = %i \n",&s_ary[0][0], __LINE__ , errno);
                return -1;
             }

        if  (s_fh_2 = open( &s_ary[1][0], O_RDONLY) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opening source file, name=%s, line# = %i, errno = %i \n",&s_ary[1][0], __LINE__ , errno);
                return -1;
             }

        if  (s_fh_3 = open( &s_ary[2][0], O_RDONLY,0) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opening source file, name=%s, line# = %i, errno = %i \n",&s_ary[2][0], __LINE__ , errno);
                return -1;
             }

        if  (s_fh_4 = open( &s_ary[3][0], O_RDONLY,0) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opening source file, name=%s, line# = %i, errno = %i \n",&s_ary[3][0], __LINE__ , errno);
                return -1;
             }

        printf("s_fh_1 = %li, s_fh_2 = %li, s_fh_3 = %li, s_fh_4 = %li \n", s_fh_1, s_fh_2, s_fh_3, s_fh_4);



        if  (s_fh_5 = open( &s_ary[4][0], O_RDONLY,0) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opening source file, name=%s, line# = %i, errno = %i \n",&s_ary[4][0], __LINE__ , errno);
                return -1;
             }

        return 0;
    }
```

terminal output:

```
    $ make

    gcc -g -c -std=iso9899:1999 -o obj/bug_tst_sync_m.o bug_tst_sync_m.c -I../include

    gcc -o bug_tst_sync_m obj/bug_tst_sync_m.o -I../include -L /usr/lib64/X11 -lX11 -lm

    $ ./bug_tst_sync_m

    s_fh_1 = 0, s_fh_2 = 0, s_fh_3 = 0, s_fh_4 = 0

    Error opening source file, name=/media/FLASH16GB_2/Test_dir/t_dir/dm5, line# = 88, errno = 2 

    $

    $
```

gcc-4.7 installation commands used on 2_10_16.

```
    update-alternatives --display gcc

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7


    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 60
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 40
    sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

makefile

```
    ### where to look for include files ( locally and globally ?   -I /usr/include/X11)
    IDIR =../include

    ### compiler to runand generate debugging info (no -g for production release code)
    CC=gcc -g

    ### list of dependencies
    CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

    ### where to put object modules
    ODIR=obj

    ### where to look for local library files locally (or write?)
    LDIR =  -L /usr/lib64/X11 -lX11

    ### libraries to include m=-lm includes the math libarary, math lib  = -lm
    LIBS=-lm

    ### list of all dependency files (.h files)
    _DEPS = queues.h InterlockedExchange.h 
    DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

    ### list of all object files
    _OBJ = bug_tst_sync_m.o
    OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

    ### compiles object modules and produces debug info   
    $(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -std=iso9899:1999 -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

    ### left side of colon is executable name 
    ### this line links objects and creates the executable
    bug_tst_sync_m: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDIR) $(LIBS) 

    ### this gets run if you type "make clean". it deletes source backup and object files.
    ### run this then next make does everything.  Without this you get situations that
    .PHONY: clean

    clean:
        rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Comment: Post the output from running your process under `strace`.  Seeing the return value of the actual `open()` system call would be very useful.  You can use the `-o /output/file/name` option to save the output of `strace` to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `<` binds harder than `=`;

```
if ( s_fh_1 = open(s1 , O_RDONLY) < 0 )
```

becomes

```
if ( s_fh_1 = ( open(s1 , O_RDONLY) < 0 ) )
```

which means, if open returns a number greater than or equal to zero, `s_fh_1` will be 0.

Comment: And the fix is to use `if ((s_fh_1 = open( s1 , O_RDONLY)) < 0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Those damn trees did it again!  I think I had a similar problem about 30 years ago when I learning C.   Getting old and rusty is the pitts.